# Lorem Ipsum Generator - Ways to have generated ipsum show in a separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lorem-ipsum

So for my design class I'm creating a Lorem Ipsum generator. Because a fixed text area with a scroller isn't all that aesthetically pleasing I'm trying to figure out a way to have it where I can have my generated lorem ipsum come up in a separate div that will then expand with the content.

[Cupcake Ipsum](http://www.cupcakeipsum.com/) does this, but my knowledge in HTML/CSS is probably considered in the mediocre range and I don't know JS all that well. From what I see they've used some sort of widget (or at least there's once mentioned in the code) to get it so that they have the generated code appear in a separate div?

Is there anyway or any tutorial available that can show me how this can be done without whatever widget they're using? I've been looking and hitting dead ends, so I don't know if I'm just not searching in the right place or what.

**So, TL;DR**: Trying to make a lorem ipsum generator. Trying to make it where the generated text doesn't show up in a text area with an ugly scroll bar, but in a separate div. Mediocre in HTML/CSS knowledge, very little JS knowledge. Help?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are putting your lorem ipsum string in a div, not in a textarea.

Divs expand according to the size of content (no scrollbars) by default. If you are seeing scrollbars, apply this css to your div:

```
#lorem_ipsum_div
{
overflow:visible;
}
```

Code to put a string in a div:

```
<div id='lorem_ipsum_div'></div>
<script>
    $('#lorem_ipsum_div').html(YOUR LOREM IPSUM STRING); //works only if using jQuery
    //if no jQuery, use this: 
    //document.getElementById("lorem_ipsum_div").innerHTML=YOUR LOREM IPSUM STRING;
</script>
```

Comment: You could also use `<p class='lorem-ipsum-output'></p>` and the jQuery selector `$('.lorem-ipsum-output')` if you want to be able to create multiple paragraphs of lipsum, a feature many generators support.